# Manually showing the bootstrap modal using the "fade" effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know the functionality that we can show up the bootstrap "modal" by using `.modal('show');`. But that just brings it up with no effect. I want to bring it up in the same way as it fades out when we click the close button.

Is that possible? Yes? How? No? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Just tried it and it works. It's controlled by the `fade` class.

Comment: I got it, I was just submitting the page again. :P